# Why thumbnail images are set automatically in the ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView with thumbnail images. All visible rows in the ListView don't have problem.
But for those new rows below the visible ones, even though I tried not to assign any images to those thumbnail `ImageViews`, images started from the first row are copied exactly the same order as in visible rows. I set breakpoints at those lines of codes assigning the images at thumbnail `ImageViews`, no breakpoints are hit but still get the images. What is the theory behind? And how can I stop assigning images automatically at the rows below the visible ones.
Thanks

EDIT1:

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(vi==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.thumbnailImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            viewHolder.activationStatus = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.activated);
            //lazy load image
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(viewHolder.thumbnailImage); 
             //if beyond visible rows, position
             //becomes zero again, at that time cnt is not zero
             //so task is not executed, to prevent image assignment
             //for rows below the visible ones 
            if(position == cnt){
                String id = listIDs.get(position);
                task.execute(id); 
                cnt++;
            }else{
                cnt = 0;

            }

    //Lazy image update
    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;  
        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            dbHelper.open();            
            byte[] img_bytes = dbHelper.getImagebyIDnumber(params[0]);          
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img_bytes, 0, img_bytes.length);        
            dbHelper.close();        
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }   


    }
```

Comment: list view recycle views. when you don't have images, you must specify that there is no image.

Comment: how can I do that? Now even I assign, still copying those from the visible rows.

Comment: start by formatting your code. for now it looks like you are declaring a named class in a method, which doesn't compile. (so i guess something is missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ListView reuses views getting invisible for visible views. If you want to hide images, you need to do this explicitly in [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of your adapter.

Comment: In getView(), I prevent not to set any images for the new rows unless I set it purposely. But still images are set at those new rows exactly the same order as those in the visible rows

Comment: Even I tried to assign an image, can't assign and still copying the images from the visible rows.

Comment: You need `else` case for `if (vi==null)` where you cancel current BitmapWorkerTask, clean image view and start new BitmapWorkerTask. If you do not do this, then you will see old view with old image.

Comment: Hi I like that idea. How to cancel and start  new BitmapWorkerTask at else loop.

Comment: Add task to your holder instance and then get it form there to call `cancel()`. To assign holder to your view use `setTag()` method. To get holder use `getTag()` method. Look for similar thread to get more information on how to use holder pattern.

Comment: thanks for passing me some hints. I refer to the link {http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/} now it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Layout. Perhaps you settet android:src = "@drawable..." by default for your images.

Configure your listView data in your adaper.

**EDITED 22.08.**

try to use this:

```
if(vi==null){
   ...
   //findView by ID here;
   ...
   vi.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
   viewHolder = ( ViewHolder ) vi.getTag();
}
//to do what you want here;
//setting values etc.
```

You can find good explanation 'how to work with ViewHolder' here [ViewHolder Pattern](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/)

Comment: Yes I have a default image to assign before setting any images. But now is those images in the visible rows are copied exactly the same order.